# What is a good way to generating thumbs?

Tags: asp.net, web, queue

On websites that allow you to upload images how are the thumbs generated?
I know imagemagick is typically used but the question is how does it work on the db end? I suspect it has a queue in a db and it can process N images at a time.

I'm talking about asp.net based websites for the moment

How does that queue work? One thought is put code in Application_Start to launch (a) thread(s) as a deamon which reads in the db for images that need to be process and sleep once no work is required.

Is this a good way or 'proper'? which way is 'good practice'

Answer (score 1):

I would not start any external threads like that within an asp.net process due to recycling.

In many cases, you can probably do it in an async page right when uploaded. If not, then perhaps a separate app (service, perhaps) which handles the queue of thumbnails needing to be generated.

Comment: 1) Is this recycling? http://www.devx.com/vb2themax/Tip/18713 wouldnt it restart the thread(s) in _start() since it restarts the entire app? 2) How would one code this separate app or service? I actually use a ManualResetEvent to sleep/wake up the said thread for immediate results.

Answer (score 1):

On our asp.net site we have used standard .Net implementation of image re-sizing and perform it on the user post of picture. Idea behind that time of post much more longer than processing of image, so place to DB 2 images (thumb and origin) is much more faster than traverse it over HTTP.

Comment: haha yes very likely. What would you do if it was a video? (maybe another answer has your thought)

Comment: @acidzombie24 well, we had another long process on indexing some text and create relations with some goods. This has been done by standalone web service (in fact it was one-way method for indexing and another to control accomplishment by AJAX). Since web-service is executed in separate thread - yes, you are right about it.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need more time processing images and video you might want to consider writing a windows service to do the processing.

You store the raw data in a temp folder and add an entry to some table in your DB which is constantly read by your service so it knows when to process data, it then reports back to your DB so you webapp knows when the data is processed. In a simpler way you could have a service monitor a folder and process whatever you put in there, moving the processed files to a 'processed files' folder.

Comment: This sounds fine but instead of doing nonstop queries how should i signal from the website to service that something is ready to be looked at? Maybe i could just check the database every 100ms which very often but not extreme?

Comment: Yes you poll every n ms or secodns even but i'd make it a variable so you can tweak it.